# Stop generating Web Forms Title automatically

Tags: asp.net, webforms, title

```
<%@ Title="" Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="" Inherits="" %>
```

Is auto-generated whenever I create a new web forms page, but I want to stop it from generating the `Title=""` section because I already have something that creates and populates titles for each of my pages.

So how do I stop it from auto-generating only that portion of the register tag?

Comment: You can't, *and you don't need to worry about it either*. If your "something" (presumably some code in a base page or something similar) sets the Title, it will be set.

Comment: @sh1rts This would be the accepted answer if I could!

Comment: I'm not bothered about scoring points ;-) just glad to help !